# Nested MySQL Query

Tags: mysql

I am new to MySQL and is trying to construct a MySQL query that does the following:

Table A:
timestamp | id_num

Table B:
dept | first_id | second_id

- Table A may contain duplicate id_nums, and the result should only return any id_num once if duplicates are present
- The id_nums must be recorded within the last week
- I want to search for any id_num that that is between first_id and second_id in table B, given one particular dept.

Here's what I have tried so far without success:

> SELECT DISTINCT id_num FROM `A` WHERE `timestamp` > '2013-09-19
>   00:00:00' AND id_num BETWEEN (SELECT `first_id` FROM `B` WHERE
>   `dept` = `X`) AND (SELECT `last_id` FROM `B`
>   WHERE `dept` = `X`)

Any tips on how to best do this type of operation?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to relate columns in two tables, you usually use a JOIN:

```
SELECT distinct id_num
FROM A
JOIN B ON A.id_num < B.first_id AND B.second_id
WHERE A.timestamp > '2013-09-19 00:00:00'
AND B.dept = X
```